# Passing unique_ptr to strtok

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I am facing an issue with the legacy code. The legacy code uses a `char` array whose size is `1024` and is being passed to `strtok` c function.

```
char record[1024] = { '\0' };
char *token = NULL;
strcpy(record, inputString);// 'inputString' very large string.
token = strtok(record, DELIMETER);
```

And now because of new requirement, I have to modify the size to 20000 bytes and in many places they have declared this type (`record`)of local variable.

Now we are compiling the code with C++11 compiler and since we are using C++11 compiler, I was planning to modify the `char` array to `unique_ptr` as shown...

```
#define MAX_RECORD 50000
auto record = std::make_unique<char[]>(MAX_RECORD * 4);
char *token = NULL;
strcpy(record.get(), inputString);
token = strtok(record.get(), DELIMETER);
```

My question is, can I pass the `unique_ptr` to `strtok` function as the `record` variable gets modified inside the `strtok` function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<char>` and pass its `.data()`?

Comment: Any thought about using a [modern approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/most-elegant-way-to-split-a-string) instead of a legacy C function?

Comment: What is `strcopy(record.get(), record);` supposed to do?

Comment: I would use `std::string` rather than allocated memory in a smart pointer.

Comment: @PasserBy: Sorry copy-paste mistake.

Comment: @NathanOliver: With the modern approach, I have to make more changes to the code and hence more testing and requires more time. But will propose this to my team.

Comment: Tbh a stack bound array is probably as good as it gets. It is high performance (compared to dynamic allocation) and cleans itself up (no memory leaks). I would not change it unless you want to modernize the whole function.

Comment: If you are planning to use C++11 and refactor the code accordingly, why don't you ditch the C leftovers entirely and use `std::string` instead of char array as well as `std::getline()` together with `std::stringstream` instead of `strtok()`? Another solution (inferior to the the first one IMO) would be using `std::vector<char>` instead of unique pointer, which will save you all these `get()` and `make_unique()` calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing a `unique_ptr` to a function represents a *transfer of ownership* of that memory to the function. And in a way, that's kind of what `strtok` does, since it will keep hold of that pointer beyond the execution of that function. But since it's a C function, it cannot effectively represent that in its interface.

What you have to do is what you're doing now: manage memory *for* `strtok`. You need to keep that `unique_ptr` alive for as long as your code requires `strtok` to be able to access it. In the previous code, it was stack memory. In your code, it's heap memory owned by a stack object. Either way, the memory ownership semantics work.

Unless the original code was broken (ie: someone called `strtok` with `NULL` outside the scope of the array). In which case your new code will be broken in the same way. Though likely, it will break more visibly.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, can I pass the unique_ptr to strtok function as the record variable gets modified inside the strtok function?

To get proper answer, you need to ask correct question. Statement that `strtok()` modifies `record` variable is incorrect, it may modify memory, where `record` points to, but it cannot modify variable `record` itself. That different things and it is important here. So answer to corrected question is no, you cannot pass `std::unique_ptr` directly to `strtok()` obviously, as it is C++ object and `strtok()` is C function. But yes, you can pass underlying pointer managed by `std::unique_ptr`, and you need to maintain lifetime of `std::unique_ptr` object itself long enough that it would not break `strtok()` requirements of that memory.

About code, it is not clear why you need `std::unique_ptr` and `strcpy()` at all:

```
std::string record = inputString;  // make a copy, if you cannot modify inputString, or pass inputString itself
token = strtok(record.data(), DELIMETER);
```

in this case you just need to maintain lifetime of variable `record` the same way, but you do not need to deal with `strcpy()` and memory allocation.